# Discord.js is there a way to create a loop for creating chat rooms

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

How to create a loop for channels?

Comment: You can use a for loop to create as many channels as you want. If you're looking for a full backup, maybe you'll be interested by this package: https://npmjs.com/discord-backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done using `setInterval()`

Code:

```js
    setInterval(() => {
        message.guild.channels.create('Test Channel', {
        type: 'text',
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
            }]
        })
    })
}
```

Loop creates channels with no `delay` or `timeout`, but be aware this code can abuse `Discord API` still you can make it Loop every 5 seconds.

Code creates text channel with `permissionOverwrites`:
`message.guild.id` is `@everyone`, with permissionOverwrites we denied `SEND_MESSAGE` for @everyone